# Using the Drupal 7's Block "description" field as a CSS class field

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

I need to add a css class to my blocks and I know I can install a module, but i rather not as it doesnt work with features. I was thinking of just using the block config's **description** field to hold my css classes and just output it in my block.tpl.php file or should i do a preprocess thing?

Now the question is what is the variable to output the block's "description"?

Comment: All blocks have already unique id's and classes derived from those id's. Why not using them?

Comment: because if your on a dev environment and you migrate your code to production. the ids will be different as the prod environment data changes if someone creates a new block. so block id's arent a reliable selector.

Comment: cool:) a var_dump() showed that the description is not passed to block.tpl.php at all. So I would go with the preprocess thingy:)

Comment: I looked into it, you need to do some nasty coding if you want to reach the description in preprocess. I rather suggest using block title directly under tpl.php with some toLower() function. If you are okey with that, I can look again and write the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you have two options:

A) Use a `_preprocess_block()` function:

```
function THEME_preprocess_block(&$vars) {
  // Make sure that this is a custom block, and not a block that is provided by
  // a module.
  if ($vars['block']->module == 'block') {
    // Load the block information.
    $info = block_custom_block_get($vars['block']->delta);
    // Add block description to the list of classes.
    $vars['classes_array'][] = $info['info'];
  }
}
```

B) Use the [Skinr](https://www.drupal.org/project/skinr) module. Probably will require more work, but it's much more flexible and editors / non-tech staff will be able to define styles of blocks. From the project page:

> Skinr's main purpose is to allow the theme to define a set of reusable and modular CSS styles, and to make those styles available in Drupal's UI.

Comment: but how do u output the "description" field ?

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: This will work on custom blocks only.

Comment: Yes, because blocks provided by other modules do not have the "Description" field, only "Block title". In either case, what OP wants is not an optimal solution. Skinr is an optimal solution though.

Comment: i rather not install anymore modules that i have already. a simple code snippet would do.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [Block Class](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_class) module, seems relatively popular and well maintained:

> Block Class allows users to add classes to any block through the block's configuration interface. By adding a very short snippet of PHP to a theme's block.tpl.php file, classes can be added to the parent  element of a block. Hooray for more powerful block theming!
>
> To add a class to a block, simply visit that block's configuration page at Administration > Structure > Blocks

Comment: features doesnt work with this.